# Cleanup SOAP header after call webservice in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, memory, soap-client

I have .webservice registered in my C# app deriving from SoapHttpClientProtocol. Remote methods are called using Invoke() method.
Everything works OK.

My problem is, I'm calling methods passing username/passw, everything is over SSL, there is no lack of security in the chanel, but, after checking in local computer sniffing in memory I can see that all the SOAP header rest in memory of the process after the call is made, so anyone with a simple tool can read the memory I get the username/passw sent to webservice.

What I want is to release the memory after call webservice's method. I already tried disposing the class, putting the class inside a "using() {}" but the information remains in memory.

There is a way to clean SOAP headers after use the webservice?

There is a way to force the memory clean or garbage collector ?

Answer (score -1):

You can force a garbage collection by calling:

```
GC.Collect()
```

Of course, you usually shouldn't do that.  Cleanup of a particular part of memory may not occur.  Also, if you're trying to force collection, you'll want to examine the results of each collection pass to see if you should call it again.

But don't.  If someone is bright enough to examine memory, they're probably bright enough to find the credentials during the short window that they're in there.

Are the user name password user supplied?  If so - it's probably just as easy to snag the credentials there.

**UPDATE:** Another thought occurred to me... You could implement the service call in a language where you have a bit more explicit control over memory (such as C++).  Then you could make the call, and explicitly write over the piece of memory that had the credentials.  The web service call part is pretty easy to do in sockets, however the SSL part is non-trivial.

Comment: well actually is a complex situation(and mainly a user request!) imagine one user enter login/passw, a webservice call is made, then another user take control of application and at this moment he can check memory and get the information passed in the call, and that's what I want to avoid.

Comment: By the way, GC.Collect() did nothing... login/passw is still there in memory. I tried also to do a second call expecting the first one was replaced and it is not, both calls are in memory with clear login/passw information... any help appreciated.

Comment: That's why I suggested that "Cleanup of a particular part of memory may not occur."  I've added another suggestion.

Comment: @Arun Do you have a better idea?  Perhaps you missed the "But don't" part of the answer?